# Byte Array operations in objective-c like java?

Tags: java, objective-c, arrays, byte

I want to implement one functionality as my ANDROID colleague did.  Below is code snippet and I am having trouble converting that code to objective-c. So please guide me in right direction--- Thanks

Here is the code snippet

```
public String createControlParams() {
        controlParams_ = "";
        String expiry = "";
        String delayedDelivery = "";
        String restricted = "";
        String priorityIndicator = "";
        String acknowledgement = "";
      //Note - PMessage.PRIORITY_INDICATOR_WHITE is defined as Int like 1,2,3
        if (priorityIndicator_ == PMessage.PRIORITY_INDICATOR_WHITE) {
            expiryTimeText_ = "";
            restrictBackup = false;
            restrictForward_ = false;
            readAcknowledgement_ = false;
        }

        if (expiryTimeText_ != null && expiryTimeText_.length() > 0) {
            int exptime = Integer.parseInt(expiryTimeText_);
            byte h = (byte) (exptime / 60);
            byte m = (byte) (exptime % 60);
            expiry = new String(new byte[]{'E', 0, h, m});//??? how to get this thing in objective-c
        }
        if (delayDelivery) {
            long timeDifference;
            long deliveryTime;
            // Fix 
//            if (midlet_.getPlatform().equalsIgnoreCase("rim")) {
////                timeDifference = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getRawOffset();
////                deliveryTime = (dateField_.getTime() - (dateField_.getTime() % (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))) + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) + deliverySetTime_ - timeDifference;//+timeDifference;//(((Integer) timeSpinner.getValue()).longValue() * 1000);
//                deliveryTime = (dateField_.getTime() + deliverySetTime_);// - timeDifference;
//            } else {
            deliveryTime = dateField_.getTime() + deliverySetTime_;// - timeDifference;
//            }
            if (deliveryTime > (new Date().getTime() + 2000)) { // Added to_ make message as instant delivery as opposed to_ delayed delivery if the delivery time is set in past (Added 2 seconds for message processing time)
                delayedDelivery = "D" + deliveryTime;
            }
        }
        if (restrictBackup && restrictForward_) {
            restricted = new String(new byte[]{'R', (byte) 3});
        } else if (restrictForward_) {
            restricted = new String(new byte[]{'R', (byte) 1});
        } else if (restrictBackup) {
            restricted = new String(new byte[]{'R', (byte) 2});
        }
        if (priorityIndicator_ == PMessage.PRIORITY_INDICATOR_RED) {
            priorityIndicator = new String(new byte[]{'P', (byte) PMessage.PRIORITY_INDICATOR_RED});
        } else if (priorityIndicator_ == PMessage.PRIORITY_INDICATOR_YELLOW) {
            priorityIndicator = new String(new byte[]{'P', (byte) PMessage.PRIORITY_INDICATOR_YELLOW});
        } else if (priorityIndicator_ == PMessage.PRIORITY_INDICATOR_GREEN) {
            priorityIndicator = new String(new byte[]{'P', (byte) PMessage.PRIORITY_INDICATOR_GREEN});
        } else if (priorityIndicator_ == PMessage.PRIORITY_INDICATOR_GRAY) {
            priorityIndicator = new String(new byte[]{'P', (byte) PMessage.PRIORITY_INDICATOR_GRAY});
        } else if (priorityIndicator_ == PMessage.PRIORITY_INDICATOR_WHITE) {
            priorityIndicator = new String(new byte[]{'P', (byte) PMessage.PRIORITY_INDICATOR_WHITE});
        }

        if (readAcknowledgement_) {
            acknowledgement = new String(new byte[]{'A', PMessage.ACK_READ});
        }

        controlParams_ = priorityIndicator;
        if (!expiry.equals("") && expiry != null) {
            controlParams_ += (byte) (-128) + expiry;
        }
        if (!delayedDelivery.equalsIgnoreCase("") && delayedDelivery != null) {
            controlParams_ += (byte) (-128) + delayedDelivery;
        }
        if (!restricted.equalsIgnoreCase("") && restricted != null) {
            controlParams_ += (byte) (-128) + restricted;
        }
        if (!acknowledgement.equalsIgnoreCase("") && acknowledgement != null) {
            controlParams_ += (byte) (-128) + acknowledgement;
        }
        return controlParams_;
//        System.out.println(controlParams_);
    }

     private void getDraftControlParms(String controlParams_) {
        if (!controlParams_.equals("") && controlParams_ != null) {
            String[] sysParams = Helpers.splitUsingStringDelim(controlParams_, String.valueOf((byte) (-128)));
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < sysParams.length; i++) {
                    if (!sysParams[i].equals("") && sysParams[i] != null) {

                        if (sysParams[i].substring(0, 1).equalsIgnoreCase("P")) {
                            priorityIndicator_ = (int) sysParams[i].getBytes()[1];
                        }

                        if (sysParams[i].substring(0, 1).equalsIgnoreCase("E")) {
                            int expiryFirstByte_ =  sysParams[i].getBytes()[2];
                            int expirySecondByte_ =sysParams[i].getBytes()[3];
                            int expiryTime=(expiryFirstByte_ * 60)  + (expirySecondByte_);
                            expiryMinutesField_.setText(expiryTime+"");
                            expiryTimeText_ = expiryMinutesField_.getText();
                        }

                        if (sysParams[i].substring(0, 1).equalsIgnoreCase("R")) {
                            int restrictedByte_ = (byte) sysParams[i].getBytes()[1];
                            if(restrictedByte_==1){
                            restrictForward_ = true;
                            restrictBackup = false;
                            }else if(restrictedByte_==2){
                            restrictForward_ = false;
                            restrictBackup = true;
                            }else{
                            restrictForward_ = true;
                            restrictBackup = true;
                            }
                        }
                        if (sysParams[i].substring(0, 1).equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
                            readAcknowledgement_ = true;
                        }
                    }

                     switch (priorityIndicator_) {
                        case PMessage.PRIORITY_INDICATOR_RED: {
                            counter.getStyle().setBgColor(0xfe0002);
                            counter.getStyle().setBgTransparency(255);
                            break;
                        }
                        case PMessage.PRIORITY_INDICATOR_YELLOW: {
                            counter.getStyle().setBgColor(0xffff00);
                            counter.getStyle().setBgTransparency(255);
                            break;
                        }
                        case PMessage.PRIORITY_INDICATOR_GREEN: {
                            counter.getStyle().setBgColor(0x80ff00);
                            counter.getStyle().setBgTransparency(255);
                            break;
                        }
                        case PMessage.PRIORITY_INDICATOR_GRAY: {
                            counter.getStyle().setBgColor(0x919594);
                            counter.getStyle().setBgTransparency(255);
                            break;
                        }
                        case PMessage.PRIORITY_INDICATOR_WHITE: {
                            counter.getStyle().setBgColor(0xffffff);
                            counter.getStyle().setBgTransparency(255);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Snippet is good lol. What do you need to convert concretely? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I m stuck at this if (expiryTimeText_ != null && expiryTimeText_.length() > 0) {
            int exptime = Integer.parseInt(expiryTimeText_);
            byte h = (byte) (exptime / 60);
            byte m = (byte) (exptime % 60);
            expiry = new String(new byte[]{'E', 0, h, m});//??? how to get this thing in objective-c
        }

Comment: I am stuck at how do I create byte array and all the things into that byte array along with (-128) byte thing also how do I seperate this in objective-c String[] sysParams = Helpers.splitUsingStringDelim(controlParams_, String.valueOf((byte) (-128)));

Comment: @RahulVyas: Why do you need to use a `String`/`NSString` to store binary data? Just use char arrays everywhere and don't convert them to/from strings all the time. (Also, unless your requirements are interoperating with an existing system, using a hand-coded binary protocol is probably a bad idea to begin with.)

Comment: I am developing same application as the java developers developed so that's why I want to keep the same format here. That is the requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an Objective C guy, but have you tried using char? In C/C++ a char is one byte and should do what you need it to.

Comment: I tried using unsigned char[] but still stuck at this 
expiry = new String(new byte[]{'E', 0, h, m});//??? how to get this thing in objective-c

Comment: I am stuck at how do I create byte array and all the things into that byte array along with (-128) byte thing also how do I seperate this in objective-c String[] sysParams = Helpers.splitUsingStringDelim(controlParams_, String.valueOf((byte) (-128)));

Comment: in C++ new std::string(char[]{ch1, ch2}). Can't help with objective C.

Comment: sure, but can't help you with that either.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use bytes.  You can use an NSArray of NSStrings.

Bytes, or unsigned char's in C, are more useful when you are concerned about the memory size of some data in a constrained environment.

Comment: the requirement is like this. The same code I need for cross platform compatibility. Can we use objective-c++ ? if yes can you please tell me how to do that?